# What other term does Singer use in regard to Continuous Moral Improvement?

Tags: ethics, terminology

I think I recall reading in [Peter Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Singer)'s "Animal Liberation" that humans, by nature, have a Continuous Moral Improvement. This was in reference to how sexism and racism are become less common, and how this could one day be the case for speciesism.

However, there was another, related term used by Singer to express the same concept. I thought it might be Kaizen, but this seems more business orientated.

So, what is the other term used by Singer?

Comment: I've never read any Singer, but I'm guessing, given his utilitarian ethics and dabbling in sociobiology, that the answer will be something like "A continuous increase in the classes of individuals and interests of those individuals taken into account in the implicit utilitarian calculus of the majority of individuals".

Comment: Tldr; I'll bet it's something to do with widening ingroups.

Comment: Hmm I think I may have worded my question wrong. I'm looking for a 1 word summary of what 'Continuous Moral Improvement' is?

Comment: One word? Why would Singer have chosen a 3 word term if one word already existed that defined it??

Comment: This by far a quote, but he said something like "Continuous Moral Improvement, also known as ........."

Comment: Don't know what term(s) Singer has used. The Sanskrit word "saadhana" might fit the requirement for a one-word answer.

Comment: Could you be looking for "perfectibility"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are looking for the term "**expanding circle**", which is also the title of one of Singer's books: *The Expanding Circle: Ethics and Sociobiology, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 1981*.

Comment: That's it! Cheers!

Comment: @Curt glad to be of help! But you weren't looking for a definition. A [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition) is usually a sentence by which a term is, well, defined. Can I rephrase your question?

Comment: Yeah I think I was asking for the opposite! Yeah, please rephrase my question if you feel you can improve it